# Zsh: Delete all files except the one in highest lexicographic sorting order

Tags: zsh

I have a set of files matching a certain glob pattern (say: *.txt). I want to remove all of them except the one which is highest in lexicographic order.

I tried to find various solutions, but even the best one I came out with, is ugly:

```
set -A files *(N)
set -A to_remove ${(O)files}
shift to_remove
foreach f in $to_remove
do
  echo rm $f
done
```

(I did not write `rm $to_remove`, because this would give an error if `to_remove` is empty).

Please give some suggestions if you know a simpler way to do it.

Comment: By “highest”, do you mean smallest or largest? E.g. given `a.txt b.txt c.txt`, do you want to keep `a.txt` or `c.txt`?

Comment: I would like to keep c.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the file names in a sorted array, use a [subscript range](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts); negative numbers count from the end.

```
if ((#files > 1)); then rm -- ${files[1,-2]}; fi
```

If the array isn't sorted, [sort it first](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

```
if ((#files > 1)); then rm -- ${${(o)files}[1,-2]}; fi
```

If you're just generating the files for this, you can do the selection from a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
files=(*.txt(N[1,-2]))
if ((#files)); then rm -- $files; fi
```

Comment: I adapted your solution to `echo *.txt(N[1,-2])|xargs rm --` . Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user1934428 Don't do that: it breaks on file names that contain whitespace or `\'"`. If you run into the command line length limit, [use zsh's builtin](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156100/what-does-this-zsh-solution-to-the-argument-list-is-too-long-do).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an array first; you can specify a range to filter the files returned by the filename expansion.

```
$ touch a b c
$ print -l *(N)
a
b
c
$ print -l *(N[1,-2])
b
c
```

Thus, you can use `rm *(N[1,-2])` to remove all but the first matching file.

You can do the same thing with an array:

```
$ foo=(a b c)
$ print -l $foo[2,-1]
b
c
```

Comment: Great, though the range should be `[1,-2]`, as @Gilles wrote in his answer.

Comment: Ah, right. I started by sorting with `O` like in your original, then dropped it and forgot to adjust the range.